# How to change the default package generation location in xtext?

Tags: xtext

How to change the default location of the generated packages in xtext?

For example: src-gen package and xtend-gen.

Inside these packages there are various sub packages are generated.So how one can change the default generation location.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How to modify **src-gen** location

Open GenerateDSL.mwe2:

- Add the following in Generator component:

  ```
  component = Generator {
      srcGenPath = "/src-other"
      ...
  }
  ```
- Modify existing directory cleaners:

  ```
  component = DirectoryCleaner {
      directory = "${runtimeProject}/src-other"
  }
  component = DirectoryCleaner {
      directory = "${runtimeProject}.ui/src-other"
  }
  component = DirectoryCleaner {
      directory = "${runtimeProject}.tests/src-other"
  }
  ```

.

---

### How to modify **xtend-gen** location

Open Eclipse Preferences then go to Xtend -> Compiler page.

You can change default Directory in section "Output folder for generated Java files"
[image]